# Consumir API con Java y recuperar los datos en objetos

Tags: java, json, api

Respecto a este ejemplo. ¿Hay una forma más simplificada para poder tener el contenido json de una api, y ya no estar iterando con BufferedInputStream con el método reader? Y con respecto a los tokens, ¿Con qué método se podría establecer en los encabezados para el envío?

Estoy usando la librería de Gson de google. Por momento es muy entendible su documentación. Se que no es la única, si tienen alguna sugerencia de otra librería, se agradece.

Esto son las librerías que estoy usando:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
```

Y el codigo:

```
try {
       URL ul1 = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1");

       HttpURLConnection urlC = (HttpURLConnection) ul1.openConnection();
       urlC.setRequestMethod("GET");

       InputStream inputStream = urlC.getInputStream();
       BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

       int readerBuffer = reader.read();

       String myJson = "";

       while(readerBuffer != -1){
                char u = (char) readerBuffer;
                myJson += u;
                readerBuffer = reader.read();
       }

       reader.close();
       inputStream.close();



       JsonParser json = new JsonParser();
       JsonObject jsonObj = json.parse(myJson).getAsJsonObject();

       String id = jsonObj.get("id").getAsString();
       String name = jsonObj.get("name").getAsString();
       String email = jsonObj.get("email").getAsString();

       System.out.println(id + ": " + name);
       System.out.println("\t email:" + email);

  } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
  } catch (IOException | NullPointerException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En particular uso la implementación Resteasy client de jaxrs 2.0, es una implementación de RedHat, y en este enlace la forma de usarla https://www.baeldung.com/resteasy-client-tutorial

Comment: Se ve muy buena esa documentación. Gracias